# ArcMap data links redirecting to location of exported map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers

This issue had only started in recent days. Just wondering if anyone else has come across this before and might know of a solution?

I have multiple mxds that contain layers that normally live in a folder called "Data" within a project folder.

So the source for these shapefiles would look something like:
D:\Project\Data

The mxd would live here:
D:\Project

Then there would be a separate folder for where the maps (JPEGs/PDFs etc.) are exported out to:
D:\Project\Maps

What seems to be happening with some of the mxds, is that the links for the data are redirecting to the maps folder after you've closed the mxd and reopened it the next day.
So instead of going to D:\Project\Data, when you reopen the mxd, the data is linking to D:\Project\Maps\Data.

We are quite certain that this is only occurring when we've just exported a map and saved the mxd (whether the order is save then export, or export then save, we're not 100% on).

This has been happening at multiple workstations with project folders and data located in different locations.
All mxds have "Store relative pathnames to data sources" checked as well.

Comment: Since you have relative paths, you don't somehow move/resave the mxd to the output (Maps) folder? It was just a thought that came to mind...

Comment: Thanks for the thought Martin. Unfortunately, moving/resaving the mxd to the maps folder doesn't change where the mxd thinks the data is located. Moving the data to the maps folder is also not an option (though that would work around the issue somewhat).

Comment: This is basically an expansion on Martin's comment: What you are describing is exactly what would happen if you saved an mxd that was using relative paths in the Project folder and then moved it to the Maps folder and opened it from there. Since relative paths are being used, ArcMap is looking for a Data folder in the current directory, since that's the structure when it was saved, and if the mxd opened from the Maps folder (after being saved in the Project folder) it would look for `D:\Project\Maps\Data`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks Dan. The only conundrum is that the mxd has never been moved from it's original location straight under D:\Project. So it's almost as if the act of exporting a map is making the mxd think that its location has changed to D:\Project\Maps. Any idea why it would be doing this? We've been working with 10.2 for a while now and it's odd that it's only just started happening in the last few days.

Comment: I've gone through and opened up the affected mxds and compared them to ones that are fine. It appears that the unaffected mxds don't have relative pathnames checked. Not sure why some are checked and others not, but I think unchecking them will solve our problem. Thank you!